# Exception in multithreading - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am triying to use multithreading using the function showed bellow:

```
import requests


def get_book_info(isbn):
    """Returns title, author and cover image URL from
    Open Library given an ISBN.

    Parameters:
    isbn (string): ISBN to search.

    Returns:
    tuple: tuple in the form (title (string), authors (list),
            cover image url (string))
    """

    openLibraryUrl = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books"
    parameters = {"bibkeys": f"ISBN:{isbn}", "format": "json", "jscmd": "data"}
    response = requests.get(openLibraryUrl, params=parameters)
    book_info = response.json()[f"ISBN:{isbn}"]

    title = book_info["title"]
    authorNames = []
    for author in book_info["authors"]:
        authorNames.append(author["name"])
    coverImageUrl = book_info["cover"]["small"] if "cover" in book_info else ""

    return (title, authorNames, coverImageUrl)
```

The input to test is:

```
isbns_to_test = ["0134692888","1491946008","1491957662","0134853989","1449340377","1449355730",
                 "1491939362","1775093301","1593279280","1593279922",
                ]
```

The code I used to do the multithreading and the one I need to correct is the following:

```
from threading import Thread

# initialize 'threads'
threads = []

for i, num in enumerate (isbns_to_test):
    thread = Thread(target = get_book_info, args =(i, num))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# stopping 'threads'
for i, thread in enumerate (threads):
    thread.join()
```

I am getting an error, which I don't know why happens. My goal is to measure the time by using `%%time`.

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-8    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-12    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: get_book_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Anyone knows why is this Error happening?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you're passing two args, `(i, num)`, to `get_book_info`, which only accepts one arg, `isbn`; why do you expect that to not produce an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function only has one parameter:

```
def get_book_info(isbn):
```

When you create the thread you pass two arguments:

```
thread = Thread(target = get_book_info, args =(i, num))
```

Either pass one argument:

```
thread = Thread(target = get_book_info, args =(num,))
```

Or add a parameter to the function signature:

```
def get_book_info(i,isbn):
```